# Htaccess url rewrite with 2 vars

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having problems with my htaccess.
I've got this url: `www.mypage.com/search.php?region=EUW&summonerName=Summonername`.
And this in my .htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ https://www.mypage.com/search.php?region=$1&summonerName=$2 [L]`

When I try to go to `www.mypage.com/EUW/Summonername` it returns 404.

Of course I've searched a lot about htaccess url rewrite before make this thread but, nothing works. What's wrong with the code? Cheers.

Edit: I've found the way using: `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ search?region=$1&summonerName=$2` Now I can do urls like `https://www.mypage.com/text/text` without problems, but I still having a problem. In my form from index.php it still redirecting to `https://www.mypage.com/search.php?region=text&summonerName=text` and I don't even don't know why. Some idea? Cheers Ladies and Gentlemans.

Comment: In the rule you are checking by for ending /, but your URL does not has that. Hence it is not working.

Comment: Your example does match the rule's regexp because of the trailing `/`.  What not try `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/? `... The trailing Q mark makes the trailing slash optional.  Also make your wildcards non-greedy:-)

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?` worked but, it redirect me to www.mypage.com/search.php?region=euw&summonerName=summonername. Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ /search.php?region=$1&summonerName=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Worked too but still redirecting and I don't know why but my php content doesn't load if i use this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the protocol. It looks like you're trying to internally rewrite `https` and I don't believe it will let you do that for security purposes. That's why it's probably still redirecting.

You should use relative paths. Try it this way and see if it works for you.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?region=$1&summonerName=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Ye I forgot to say that I'm using https. So it works but still redirecting. I'm so lost.

Comment: Make sure to clear your browser cache or try in a new browser to check it the new rules.